# How to display checked boxes in a php for-loop function?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to get the selected checkboxes in the form to be put in an array and then displayed in the 2nd .php file, which is the 2nd element at the bottom.

```
<?php

$data = array("images/architecture-57e8d34a48_640.jpg",
"images/gateway-arch-57e2d64548_640.jpg",
"images/horseshoe-bend-57e6d6434f_640.jpg",
"images/lake-irene-57e6d24a4d_640.jpg",
"images/silhouette-57e8d5444e_640.jpg");

function displayCheckboxes($data){
  for ($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++) {
  echo "<br><input type='checkbox' id='chkimg' name='chkimg[]' value='photo'>
  <img id='photo' src='".$data[$i]."'>" . "<br><br>";
  }
}

function greetings1(){
    return "Thank you ";
}

function greetings2(){
    return " for your submission!";
}

displayCheckboxes($data);
?>


<main id ="main">
      <h1>Best Pics</h1>
      <form id="pics" action="process.php" method="get">
        <label id="label">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="user" id="name">
        <h2>Check Your Favorite Pics</h2>
        <?php include 'functions.inc.php' ?>
        <? php echo displayCheckboxes(); ?>
        <button type="submit"> Click here to submit </button>
      </form>
</main>


<main id = "main">
   <?php include 'functions.inc.php' ?>    
       <h2><?php echo greetings1().$_GET['user'].greetings2();?></h2>
   <? php echo displayCheckboxes(); ?>
</main>
```

I know I have to use something like

```
if (isset($_POST['chkimg'])) 
{
    print_r($_POST['chkimg']); 
}
```

But I am having trouble on where to insert it.

Answer (score 0):

You would put it within your 2nd php file as follows (although you seem to be mixing up POST and GET methods):

```
<main id = "main">
<?php include 'functions.inc.php' ?>    
   <h2><?php echo greetings1().$_GET['user'].greetings2();?></h2>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['chkimg'])) {
   echo displayCheckboxes();
}
?>

</main>
```

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry about that,the user ID already has a GET and I forgot about it. Thank you